# How to calculate array size in preprocessor time?

Tags: c, arrays, size, c-preprocessor

I want to create a array with the size that is calculated in the preprocessor by means of defines. When I try to initialize this array "memory" the following error appears:

*error: expression must be an integral constant expression*

This look the me that the expression that gives the size appears to be variable, which is weird because it is calculated from defines. See the following code:

```
#define SAMPLE_FREQUENCY_HZ 48000
#define SAMPLE_INTERVAL_MS ((1.0 / SAMPLE_FREQUENCY_HZ) * 1000.0)
#define MAX_DELAYLINE_LENGHT_MS 250
#define MAX_DELAYLINE_LENGHT_ELEM (MAX_DELAYLINE_LENGHT_MS / SAMPLE_INTERVAL_MS)

typedef struct {
    float delay;
    int size;
//    float *memory;
    float memory[MAX_DELAYLINE_LENGHT_ELEM];
    float *start;
    float *end;
    float *writePointer;
    float *readPointer;
} delayline_t;
```

Could someone explain the problem en give me a solution the solve this in a need way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression that determines the array size of a member in the struct, must be an *integer constant expression*.

> 6.6 Constant expressions
>
> 6. An integer constant expression 117) shall have integer type and shall only have operands
>    that are integer constants, enumeration constants, character constants, sizeof
>    expressions whose results are integer constants, _Alignof expressions, and floating
>    constants that are the immediate operands of casts. Cast operators in an integer constant
>    expression shall only convert arithmetic types to integer types, except as part of an
>    operand to the sizeof or _Alignof operator.

As you can see, floating point types are not allowed in this expression.

You will have to manually pre-compute the values of your macros, round them to integer values, and then include them into the program.

Answer (score 1):

`MAX_DELAYLINE_LENGHT_ELEM` is a float/double but an array size must be integral.

It resolves to :

```
(250 / (1.0 / 48000*1000.0)) =12222.0
```

but to the compiler it is still a double.

Answer (score 0):

The array size needs to be an integer constant.

Suggest 3 changes: A) Change to nanoseconds.  B) use *rounded* integer calculations 2) "LENGTH" (spelling)

```
#define SAMPLE_FREQUENCY_HZ (48000 /* Hertz */ )

#define SAMPLE_INTERVAL_ns \
    ((1000UL*1000*1000 + SAMPLE_FREQUENCY_HZ/2)/ SAMPLE_FREQUENCY_HZ)

#define MAX_DELAYLINE_LENGTH_ns (250UL*1000*1000 /* nano seconds */)

#define MAX_DELAYLINE_LENGTH_ELEM \
    ((MAX_DELAYLINE_LENGTH_ns + SAMPLE_INTERVAL_ns/2)/ SAMPLE_INTERVAL_ns)
```